# onbeforeunload keeps poping up an alert box when user click something

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am created a page that warns the user when they click on the (close <kbd>x</kbd>) button on the window. I did some reading and discovered that JavaScript had a function called `onbeforeonload` which can take of the job I was trying to achieve. I however found at after my implementation that, when a user clicks on anything in my window (example: save and enter) The dialog box reappears. I was wondering how I could only target the specific <kbd>X</kbd> button in the window.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
  var message = 'Do you want to leave?';
  if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
    evt = window.event;
  }
  if (evt) {
    evt.returnValue = message;
  }
  return message;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you clarified the question. See tips at http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the function is being called globally... this resource might help you achieve what you are looking for: http://randomdrake.com/2009/09/23/how-to-use-onbeforeunload-with-form-submit-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

This is a "working as intended" behavior for IE. Anchor tag clicks, regardless of whether they navigate or not, will trigger the [`onbeforeunload` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This is the workaround I used - I am not sure whether it is the best approach or not:

```
document.onmouseup = function () {
    if (window.event.srcElement.tagName === 'A') {
        // turn off your onbeforeunload handler
        ...

        // some small time later, turn it back on
        setTimeout(..., 200);
    }
};
```